Emulator issue - system UI isn't responding
I am doing a course with Udemy on coding. I am required to use Android Studio Hedgehog 2023 1.1 RC (Oct 17 2023 version) with the Pixel 7 API 34 'upside down cake emulator'. I am having an issue with my emulator. It keeps saying  it says 'system UI isn't responding'.
I have uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio but the problem is persisting. I also tried the 'wipe data' option that Google suggested. I tried another emulator and the same is happening.
